# Javascript clock function not running on Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

First real time I've tried to use Javascript in a Rails app, but nothing outside of alerts seem to be working for me.

What I'm trying to do is get this [simple clock](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) to run on my Rails app, pretty much copying the code where I thought it was supposed to go, but nothing's working and all my searches are either too specific or don't seem to work.

I want the clock to be available sitewide but I've also tried organizing it onto specific controllers and their views with the same amount of luck.

**application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree ./sitewide
```

**apps/assets/javascripts/sitewide/pages.js**

```
function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Clawk</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>


</head>
<body>


<%= render 'shared/navbar' %>

<div class="container-fluid">

<%= render 'shared/sidebar' %>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
<div id="txt"></div>
<%= yield %>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you run `startTime();` in the JavaScript console, does the clock appear?

Comment: Why yes, yes it does. And I'm feeling more and more like a newbie by the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the JavaScript in place, but you are not actually calling the `startTime()` function. Note in the example it is called via an `onload` attribute on `body`: `<body onload="startTime()">`

With Rails, you could add this to the end of your `pages.js` file:

```
$(document).on('page:load', function() {
  startTime();
});
```

This will execute the code within the function on page load (and will be compatible with turbolinks).